# How to align text for specific element in a list python

Tags: python

ok Im trying to take the contents from another file and parse them.

So my Columns look like this after parsing:

```
Data|   Pin   |  Time   |  Delay  |
800 |   address |  15  |   23
```

How can I make the text look like this:

Edit:

is it possible to have this format:

```
Data |        Pin        |  Time  |  Delay  |
800  |   LONG PIN NAME   |   16   |   15    |
```

Each column aligment should be different based on the lenght of string.

I know I can use `.split('|')` to make the lines into a list but how to I make it so that each column uses a specific number of spaces and does not go pass that. So for example:

```
for lines in file:
    #align lines
    #write lines. align to new file
```

this will then be sent from unix to outlook email, so for some reason the columns always get unaligned in unix if one element in a column is too long and they are always out of aligment in outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.format` and specify a justification:

```
In [199]: lines = '''Data|   Pin   |  Time   |  Delay  |
     ...: 800 |   address |  15  |   23 |'''.splitlines()

In [200]: for line in lines:
     ...:     print('|'.join(['{:^10}'.format(x) for x in map(str.strip, line.split('|'))])
     ...: )
     ...:     
   Data   |   Pin    |   Time   |  Delay   |          
   800    | address  |    15    |    23    |
```

You need to first split on `|`, then strip each item to remove extraneous whitespace. You can then apply the formatting and join on `|` once again.

Do not mix tabs and spaces.

---

For variable spacing, you can create a spacing list and pass it to the string inside, like this:

```
spacing = [10, 20, 8, 8]

for line in lines:
    print('|'.join([('{:^%d}' %sp).format(x) for sp, x in zip(spacing, map(str.strip, line.split('|')))]))

   Data   |        Pin         |  Time  | Delay  
   800    |      address       |   15   |   23
```

Comment: The ```'{:^10}'``` needs to be wide enough to accomodatre the longest string being printed. - [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: @wwii Indeed. The 10 was just an estimate. I assume OP would make the change if needed.

Comment: This is perfect but for example data has a maximum of 6 numbers and pin name could be 15 characters is there a way to not have to use 15 characters to align all of them as a colum for example

Column one could be

 800 |     PIN_NAME_LONG |   800  | ANOTHER LONG NAME |

Comment: @AlexanderVelez Yeah. You could do something like store your desired widths in a list, and then you can zip the line and the width list, and set the width dynamically inside the list comp.